# GemBox Spreadsheet : Why Save Excel to PDF PieChart cannot show same in Excel

Tags: c#, .net-5, gembox-spreadsheet

[from Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnuTJ.png)

[from PDF Export From Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYuAK.png)

This Code export Pie Chart

```
    //Pie Chart
    var pieChart = worksheet.Charts.Add(ChartType.Pie, "A27", "G45");
    pieChart.SelectData(worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("G2:G6"), true, true);
    pieChart.DataLabels.LabelContainsValue = true;
    pieChart.DataLabels.LabelContainsPercentage = true;
    pieChart.DataLabels.ShowLeaderLines = true;
    pieChart.DataLabels.Separator = ", ";
    pieChart.Legend.IsVisible = true;
    pieChart.Legend.Position = ChartLegendPosition.Bottom;

    var printOptions = worksheet.PrintOptions;
    printOptions.FitWorksheetWidthToPages = 1;
    printOptions.FitWorksheetHeightToPages = 1;
    workbook.Save(ms, SaveOptions.PdfDefault);`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is with [`LabelContainsPercentage`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/docs/GemBox.Spreadsheet.Charts.ChartDataLabels.html#GemBox_Spreadsheet_Charts_ChartDataLabels_LabelContainsPercentage) which is currently not supported in output PDF., see the property's remarks. This will be added in the future, but for now, you'll need to use those percentage values in the chart series so that you have them with `LabelContainsValue`.